# How to set timezone to "America/SaoPaulo" in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, date, next.js, timezone

I'm currently working on a project using Next.js 13 and I'm facing an issue with timezone settings. I'm based in Brazil (America/Sao_Paulo timezone), and all the dates displayed in my application have a discrepancy of approximately 3 hours. I suspect that the default timezone used by Next.js is different from what I need.

Could someone guide me on how to properly set the timezone to "America/SaoPaulo" in Next.js 13? I've searched through the documentation but couldn't find a clear solution for this specific version.

I've tried using the date-fns library to manually adjust the dates to the correct timezone, but it seems cumbersome and error-prone

Comment: Short answer, you can't. Your clients could be anywhere, but your server is in one time zone: this is a fundamental problem of any web app. The solution is to have your client adjust the date to use UTC. That way, both your client and server "speak" UTC, and your client can always localize the dates it gets from the server (for whatever timezone your client is in) after it receives it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Time zone settings aren't part the responsibility of Next.js or any other such framework.  As for the solution described in Fabio's comment, that is one approach but it doesn't necessarily apply to every scenario you might encounter with dates and times.  You'll need to be much more specific about what exactly you're doing, providing context and code examples.

Comment: Also, the only _question_ you asked is, "Could someone guide me...".   Generally, that's too vague, and is not what StackOverflow is about.  Instead, you should ask a _specific_ question.  You should read [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks.